# Few content types in a View

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I use Drupal 8 and I need to create a view with few content types. When I navigate to a specific path, I need to list all of them at the same time, but I need something like a filter so that in this view only particular content type is displayed. How can I do it?

Comment: Click on Add filter, and add type, check-mark expose filter.

Comment: I did, unfortunately the filter is not displayed

Comment: well that's unfortunate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a Contextual filter.

You create a Page Display with a path of your choosing that is displaying many Content types. This is your page that lists all of them, for example `my-content-types`.

Then you add a Contextual filter to that View called **Content type** from `Content` Category.

Configure it with these options:
    `When the filter value is NOT in the URL`
    **Display all results for the specified field**
    `When the filter value IS in the URL or a default is provided`
    **Specify validation criteria**
    `Validator` **Content type**
    `Case in path` **Lower case**
    `More`
    **Transform spaces to dashes in URL**

You can leave other options as default, although you should read them all and adjust to your needs, for example what Views should do in case your argument doesn't validate, or you need more than one content type filter on the same page.

This Contextual filter adds options to your path based on the content types you have on your system. If you add the name of a content type to your path (in your browser Location bar): 
`my-content-types/article` the Views results will reduce the list to only show Article nodes.

If you enter a path `my-content-types/page` it will list only Basic page nodes.

There is also an option to override the Title if you need to correct it to name only the content types filtered out.

If you set your Contextual filter to allow multiple values (there are two places for that) you can construct the path with two or more content types to filter them out: `my-content-types/page+article`.

To test that your Contextual filter is working you can enter the argument for it in the `Preview with contextual filters:` field and hit the `Update preview` button if you don't have it set automatically. To view all the results without filtering simply delete the argument or enter `all` at the Preview or at the end of your path.

Comment: I'm glad to help! Don't forget to accept the answer if it does solve your problem ;)